# Why is my Bootstrap navigation bar not quite responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I coded a navigation bar with three links. The navigation bar should be responsive which means that if the window becomes small enough the links should disappear (as they do) and a new button with three horizontal lines should appear (which does not).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="btn btn-navbar" class="navbar-toggle"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/server">APL</a>
            </div>


            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div
                class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="documentation.html">Documentation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Why does the button in the following JSFiddle demo stay invisible (same markup)?

http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/22/

Comment: Does the collapse plugin included? On the fiddle you shared there is no bootstrap js, which required for the collapse functionality to work.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to include that. Ok I just updated the demo code, the behaviour nevertheless did not change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The menu button is there, but it's white so you can't see it.

Add `navbar-inverse` class to the navbar and it shows up:

http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/23/

**UPDATE**

Your original question only asked *“Why does the button in the following JSFiddle demo stay invisible”* and my above jsfiddle example solved that. But per your comment below, I looked at your jsfiddle again.

The reason the menu button wasn't toggling the menu was you didn't have a valid link to `bootstrap.min.js` nor did you **preload jQuery**. After adding both, you can see your demo works: **http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/25/**

Comment: I just rechecked your proposal. Although the menu button is shown now it does not contain any elements. The links are still missing.

Comment: Well your question specifically said "Why does the button in the following JSFiddle demo stay invisible" and so that is what I answered. To make the button show and hide the menu, you have to initialize the proper JavaScript plugin

Answer (score 0):

This is a JsFiddle issue.

I already got this one, with a Bootstrap-3 navbar. Your code perfectly works, you can try it in a blank file. You can also copy paste the Bootstrap-3 navbar example to see the issue.

[A working JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/ehUyoJe/1/edit)

Comment: It's actually not a jsFiddle issue, but a user issue. The original jsFiddle example did not include **jQuery** and the link to `bootstrap.min.js` was invalid

Comment: Same result, various causes. Well done for pointing the broken link.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's JavaScript was incorrectly linked in the jsFiddle. It was added without an `http://` and was linking to `jsfiddle.net`.

Also, Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery, but the Fiddle did not include it.

I fixed the reference to Bootstrap's JS and added jQuery as a dependency. I also inverted the colors on the navbar so you could see it more easily with `navbar-inverse`. Everything works great:

http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/24/

Answer (score 0):

I put your menu code into my boilerplate BS3 nav bar template and it works.  Tested in Firefox 17, Chrome 29 and IE8 (I my environment I have to support IE8, so I included some info about that, too).  Let me know if you have need anything else or have any questions.

UPDATE: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ySPLM/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title>Bootstrap Sample</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--
SET UP THE FOLLOWING FOR YOUR ENVIRONMENT IF YOU WANT TO SUPPRT IE8.
See https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond for more. Note that the Respond.js script 
will not function locally in IE8 due to browser security restrictions.
-->
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="btn btn-navbar"
                class="navbar-toggle"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/server">APL</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
                <li><a href="documentation.html">Documentation</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```